# Heroku and some website in the net. can I know that a website uses Heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have noticed something curious recently. When I try to open some sites, it appears a Heroku log. For instance, I was trying to access a Brazilian website for investment, and it says that the website is offline for maintenance, and shows the Heroku log, not the domain. I believe if you pay, they will give you your own domain, without the Heroku name that normally we have. I am trying to convince my current team to use Heroku in our project. Is there a list of sites using Heroku publicly available?

Answer (score 0):

If your looking for justification for using Heroku you might just look at their [testimonial page](https://www.heroku.com/customers).

If you're trying to figure out how to set up custom domains with Heroku I would recommend [Heroku's Docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains)

Comment: "FYI you can use Heroku and use a custom domain for free if you set up a CNAME to point to the Heroku URL on your DNS!" can you give me more detail here? It seems nice. I already have a domain, from the institution. But, it is based on Apache. I was able to make it run, but some issues use to come up.

Comment: I would google how to set up a CNAME record, but it'll have the Heroku Url as the value and your domain or subdomain as the name

Comment: Your welcome, I edited the answer so that all the useful data is all in the post. And if the post did help you please upvote and accept the answer so that others can find it!

Comment: Hi Niles Tanner, I cannot accept the answer or upvote it. It seems I need to gain a level of points first, I am new here!